# How can i run an application in remote computer and wait for results using .net c#

Tags: c#, .net

My requirement is to run a calculation in an external computer or remote computer
and wait for the application to finish the calculation and return the results.

Is this possible in C# .net and if so how can I get this done?

I tried psexec but it doesn't wait for response

Comment: Yes this is possible.  What have you tried?  How do you have to run the calculation exactly?

Comment: You can use .net remouting or WCF.

Answer (score 0):

**Use WCF with asynchronous call;** 
Create  a WCF service and add that service to your project while "*Generate async operations*" is selected on the *Service Reference Settings* screen of Visual Studio. This will add *asynchronous* operation capabilities to your services for example;

if your service name is sumNumbers(int x, int y) then Visual studio will generate sumNumbersCompleted event for  you automatically. So you can call your service as follows;

```
sumNumbers(5,6);
sumNumbersCompleted+=methodWhentheEventisCompleted;
```